# How to put image borders around the main content in Blogger

Tags: html, background-image, css

To make my site look more professional and neater, I'd really like to include top and bottom borders to the main content. Here's what I mean: http://prntscr.com/29k16m

I know this picture is rather blurry. So if you would like the full picture of my progress so far in achieving this, here it is (under the first grey box) : http://aergaergerg.blogspot.com.au/

I'm not really sure what coding to include as I'm only a kid and not very experienced in coding.. and also as there's bits and pieces of this certain bit of coding all over the place. Here's some:

```
<Variable name="main.background" description="Main Background" type="background"
   default="transparent url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-_axW0fhAC2Y/UqPOKPHt6EI/AAAAAAAADeg/0FbGNIS9E2o/s1600/mainbody2.png) repeat scroll top
 left" value="transparent url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-_axW0fhAC2Y/UqPOKPHt6EI/AAAAAAAADeg/0FbGNIS9E2o/s1600/mainbody2.png) repeat scroll top
 left"/>
   <Variable name="main.padding.sides" description="Main Padding Sides" type="length"
default="20px" value="20px"/>
```

Separate HTML coding found later in the template:

```
/* Main ----------------------------------------------- */
.main-outer {
  background: $(main.background);

  -moz-border-radius: $(main.border.radius.top) $(main.border.radius.top) 0 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: $(main.border.radius.top);
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: $(main.border.radius.top);
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -goog-ms-border-radius: $(main.border.radius.top) $(main.border.radius.top) 0 0;
  border-radius: $(main.border.radius.top) $(main.border.radius.top) 0 0;

  -moz-box-shadow: 0 $(region.shadow.offset) $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 $(region.shadow.offset) $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -goog-ms-box-shadow: 0 $(region.shadow.offset) $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  box-shadow: 0 $(region.shadow.offset) $(region.shadow.spread) rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.main-inner {
  padding: 15px $(main.padding.sides) 20px;
}

.main-inner .column-center-inner {
  padding: 0 0;
}

.main-inner .column-left-inner {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.main-inner .column-right-inner {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

So yeah, I'm sorry if those bits of codes aren't very relevant but I wasn't entirely sure what to put.. but all I need is top borders on my main content :) (the background around the post+sidebar)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

here's a classic 5 pixel, light gray border with rounded corners and a drop shadow. You can place this in your css file, and reuse it by applying it to different elements within your site. Add this style to **the div that contains** your image or contents like so:

HTML

```
<div id="Header3" class="rounded-border widget Header">
```

CSS

```
.rounded-border {
border:5px solid #cccccc;
box-shadow:1px 1px 5px 2px rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.50);
-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px 2px rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.50);
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px 2px rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.50);
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-khtml-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
}
```

Tip
When you have a really wide image or content that goes beyond the browser window/viewport, the div will only fill the window, and not include the contents that overflow into the horizontal scrollable area. This is the default behavior. If you want the div to wrap around the overflowing contents, you have several options:

- You can leave it as is
- You can use overflow hidden (this will hide overflowing contents, so use with caution)
- You can make the div wrap around the contents by applying a float, an inline-block, or display table to the container div. [Shrink To Fit Tutorial](http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/CSS-Shrink-Wrap) and here's the [browser compatibility tables](http://caniuse.com/)
- You can use the "Fluid Image" technique to make the image adjust to its contents. [Fluid Image Tutorial](http://alistapart.com/article/fluid-images)

[Here's a JSFiddle you can play with](http://jsfiddle.net/8uBgR/)